# Prolog cousin once removed and half sister/brother rules

Tags: prolog

Am working on a prolog genealogy project and cannot figure out how to make the rules for cousin once removed and half sister/brother rules. Below is what I have and cannot get it to work. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. I have placed in bold what I have tried. I'm sure its something simple in the way I'm trying to code it.I just cannot figure it out.

```
person(marc,male).
person(faith,female).
person(alan,male).
person(kim,female).
person(missy,female).
person(eric,male).
person(charles,male).
person(eleanor,female).
person(roland,male).
person(corey,male).
person(amy,female).
person(tyler,male).
person(matty,male).
person(kaydi,female).
person(jenna,female).
person(allison,female).
person(emma,female).
person(hayley,female).
person(jaylin,female).
person(lukus,male).
person(brendon,male).
person(bradley,male).
person(tylerh,male).
person(dayna,female).
person(victor,male).
person(jacoby,male).
person(javi,male).
person(jordan,male).
person(jaxson,male).
person(kenzie,female).
person(richard,male).
person(reggie,male).
person(reggiejr,male).
person(beverly,female).
person(floyd,male).
person(marjorie,female).
person(kevin,male).


parent(marc,alan).
parent(faith,alan).
parent(charles,marc).
parent(charles,kim).
parent(charles,missy).
parent(charles,eric).
parent(eleanor,marc).
parent(eleanor,kim).
parent(eleanor,missy).
parent(eleanor,eric).
parent(eric,matty).
parent(eric,tyler).
parent(eric,kaydi).
parent(amy,matty).
parent(amy,tyler).
parent(amy,kaydi).
parent(missy,jordan).
parent(missy,jaxson).
parent(missy,kenzie).
parent(richard,jordan).
parent(corey,kenzie).
parent(corey,jaxson).
parent(kim,allison).
parent(kim,jenna).
parent(kim,emma).
parent(kim,jaylin).
parent(kim,hayley).
parent(kim,dayna).
parent(roland,allison).
parent(roland,jenna).
parent(roland,emma).
parent(roland,jaylin).
parent(roland,hayley).
parent(roland,dayna).
parent(dayna,javi).
parent(dayna,jacoby).
parent(victor,javi).
parent(victor,jacoby).
parent(jenna,bradley).
parent(brendon,bradley).
parent(tylerh,lukus).
parent(allison,lukus).
parent(reggie,reggiejr).
parent(beverly,reggiejr).
parent(floyd,beverly).
parent(marjorie,beverly).
parent(reggiejr,kevin).
parent(floyd,eleanor).
parent(marjorie,eleanor).


married(marc,faith).
married(charles,eleanor).
married(kim,roland).
married(eric,amy).
married(missy,corey).
married(dayna,victor).
married(allison,tylerh).
married(marjorie,floyd).
married(beverly,reggie).





father(X, Y)             :-   parent(X, Y),  person(X,male).
mother(X, Y)             :-   parent(X, Y),  person(female,Y).

son(X, Y)                :-  parent(Y,X),    person(X,male).
daughter(X, Y)           :-  parent(X,Y),    person(Y,female).
grandparent(X, Z)        :-  parent(X, Y),  parent(Y, Z).
grandfather(X, Z)        :-  grandparent(X, Z),  person(X,male).
grandmother(X, Z)        :-  grandparent(X, Z),  person(female,Y).
grandson(X, Z)           :-  grandchild(X, Z),  person(X,male).
granddaughter(Y, Z)      :-  grandchild(Y, Z),  person(Y,female).
grandchild(X, Z)         :-  grandparent(Z, X).
sibling(X,Y)             :- parent(Z,X),    parent(Z,Y).  
brother(Y, X)            :- sibling(Y,X),  person(X,male), not(X=Y).
sister(X, Y)             :-  sibling(X, Y),  person(Y,female).       

auntoruncle(X, W)        :-  sibling(X, Y), parent(Y, W).
auntoruncle(X, Z)        :-  married(X,Y),  sibling(Y,W),    parent(W,Z).
uncle(X, W)              :- auntoruncle(X, W),    person(X,male).
aunt(X, W)               :- auntoruncle(X, W),     person(female,Y).
cousin(X, Y)             :-  parent(Z, X),  auntoruncle(Z, Y), Y\=X.
nieceornephew(X, Y)      :-  parent(Z, X),  sibling(Z, Y).
nephew(X, Y)             :-  nieceornephew(X, Y), person(X,male).
niece(X, Y)              :-  nieceornephew(Y, X), person(Y,female).
greatgrandparent(X, Z)   :-  parent(X, Y),  grandparent(Y, Z).
greatgrandfather(X, Z)   :-  greatgrandparent(X, Z),  person(X,male).
greatgrandmother(X, Z)   :-  greatgrandparent(X, Z),  person(female,Y).
greatgrandchild(X, Z)    :-  child(X, Y),   grandchild(X, Z).
greatgrandson(X, Z)      :-  greatgrandchild(X, Z), person(X,male).
greatgranddaughter(X, Z) :-  greatgrandchild(X, Z),  person(female,Y).
married_to(X,Y) :- married(X,Y), not divorced(X,Y).
whatgender(X,Y)     :- person(X,Y). 

**child(X, Y)              :-  parent(Y, X).
cousinonceremoved(X, Y)  :-  cousin(Z, Y), child(X, Z).
halfsibling(X,Y) :- parent(Z,X), parent(Z,Y), parent(P,X), \+parent(P,Y).
halfbrother(X,Y) :- halfsibling(X,Y), male(X).
halfsister(X,Y) :- halfsibling(X,Y), female(X).**
```

**strong text**

Comment: What exactly did you query and what exactly doesn't work or goes wrong? Error message? Incorrect results?

Comment: One of the queries I tried was:           ?-cousinonceremoved(marc,X)       which should be kevin and all I got was a no.

Comment: Did you try using `trace.`?

Comment: never heard of trace am looking up how to use it thanks and new to prolog

Comment: If you enter `trace.` then your query, you'll get a detailed step-by-step execution of your predicate. It can be tedious but can show you what's going on. You turn it off by entering `notrace.`.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include **the desired behavior**, a **specific problem** or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Also, since your predicate is defined as, `cousinonceremoved(X, Y)  :-  cousin(Z, Y), child(X, Z).` and your query was `cousinonceremoved(marc, X)` you could first try testing `child(X, Z)`, see if the results make sense. Break it down.

Comment: child(X,Z). shows the right data. cousin(Z,Y). is correct except it shows me as being cousins with my brother and sisters.

Comment: Also noticed many of the cousins are missing

Comment: lurker, thanks for your suggestions. Am having issues with getting trace to work. Maybe from lack of knowledge. Still haven't figured out why its not working. Going to keep plugging away at it.

Comment: Have got the half sister/brother rule figured out. Still not sure what is going wrong with my cousins once removed rule. Am stumped.